# Android webview Samsung Galaxy S3 / note not receiving text input

Tags: android, webview, samsung-mobile, galaxy

I've been struggling for a few hours/days now trying to figure out why only on samsung devices would the webview not receive any input in a text field, it appears to be fine on other manufactures e.g Sony and nexus just not Samsung Note running 4.1

The input box gets focus and the keyboard highlights the selected letter it just does not appear in the input text field, but there is one strange thing it will accept other certain characters e.g. € £ and other foreign characters just no other standard ones or numbers.

I have tried a few different things like webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); and webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN); neither did the trick :(

The page I am trying to do input on is on the web and not an internal page, but the same issue happens when using google. e.g.

[image: webview issue on samsung galaxy note 4.1 and other samsung devices]

Comment: The problem seems to be related to the Samsung keyboard, if you install Gboard it should work.